# Add Hibernate Dependency on pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, pom.xml, eclipselink

Problem:

While copying the Hibernate dependency code from the https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core link and adding it to the Maven Project in Eclipse, the Hibernate-core library is not getting installed. This prevents the project from building successfully.

Replace the initial code:

xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

with the following code:

xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
```

The corrected dependency uses the `org.hibernate.orm` group ID and specifies version 6.3.0.CR1 for the Hibernate-core library.

Once you update your project's pom.xml file with the corrected dependency, Maven should be able to resolve and download the correct Hibernate-core library without any issues. Don't forget to refresh your project in Eclipse to ensure the changes are properly detected.

Comment: This sounds like a question with a self-answer. This is fine, but please provide the answer not as part of the question, but as an answer of its own.

Comment: I do not know why this is closed. The solution is: 6.2.7.Final **is not packaging-type pom but jar !!!**